# Check duplicated values in excel by filtering two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 50000 rows of data set example of the data:

[image: pic]

Or here:

```batch-file
 code ID  NUMBER
       1       1
       2←      2←
       2←      2←
       3       7
       3       9
       4       1
       5       4
       5       6
       6←      2←
       6←      2←
       7       8
       8       3
       8       4
       8       5
       9       5
      10       5
      11       8
      11       9
      12       5
      12       6
      12       7
      13       9
      14       4
      15       8
      15       9
      16       9
```

I want to check where is the values are duplicate

For example, you can see rows `10` and `11` that I colored in the picture for this post, or at the `code` part where I added **`←`** on some rows of it, and that means where the third column will be notified this is duplicated row.

I want to add another column that say if it is duplicated or not.
I search a while and I don't find an answer for that, there is an option to do that?

Answer (score 1):

In **C3** enter:

<strike>=IF(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2),"dup","")</strike>

and copy downwards.

**EDIT#1:**

Use this in **C3** instead:

```
=IF(OR(AND(A3=A2,B3=B2),AND(A3=A4,B3=B4)),"dup","")
```

Comment: The command you have wrote will work for the first row (where it's false) in the second (where it's true), but in the third row the if statement will be false while there is a duplicate row ('dup' should be shown on the both rows)

Comment: @RamRahamim  I will try to fix!

Comment: @RamRahamim  See my **EDIT#1**